# Erro na saída ao tentar imprimir conteúdo do arquivo.txt

Tags: c, memória, alocação

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>

typedef struct{

    char **matriz;

} Dado;


void ler_agumento (Dado *dado, int argc, char **argv){

    int opcao;
    dado -> matriz = NULL;

    while (opcao = getopt (argc,argv, "e::") != -1){

        switch (opcao){

            case 'e':
                dado->matriz = optarg;
                break;
        }
    }
}

void imprimir (FILE *file){

    char *line = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));

    if(file == NULL) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Erro ao abrir o arquivo.txt.");
    }   

    while(fgets(line, 80, file) != NULL) {

        printf("%s", line);
    }     
}

int main(int argc, char **argv[]){

    int i;
    Dado dado;

    dado.matriz = malloc(sizeof(char *)*8);

        for(i=0; i<8; i++){

            dado.matriz[i] = malloc(8);
        }

    ler_argumento (&dado, argc, argv);

    FILE *file = fopen(dado.matriz,"r");

    imprimir (file);

    fclose (file);

    return 0;
}
```

Quero imprimir o conteúdo que está dentro de um arquivo. Passei como argumento pelo terminal abrindo dessa forma (`./executar -e arquivo.txt`). A saída que gera é a mensagem de erro do `printf()` mostrando que o arquivo está vazio e em seguida mostra *segmenttion fault*.

Comment: Aqui:  malloc(sizeof(char)) você está alocando espaço para um único caractere. Talvez devesse ser:  malloc(80*sizeof(char)). O array para conter a string"arquivo.txt" deveria ter pelo menos tamanho 12 e não 8.

Comment: Boa noite! Fiz essa modificação mas a saída continou a mesma.

Comment: Você faz `dado->matriz = optarg;` mas `char** matriz` e `char* optarg` são incopatíveis. `argv` deveria ser `char** argv` ou `char* argv[]`

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas. Fiz as alterações deixando char *matriz e char **argv. A saida continua da mesma forma

Answer (score 2):

Precisa mesmo desta abstração para o dado? O principal motivo de problema no código e que causa o erro descrito é a falta de alocação de memória para armazenar os dados. Também tem um erro na assinatura da função `main()`. Melhorei mais algumas coisas, mas tem cara de ter um erro de lógica aí (não vou afirmar porque não sei o requisito), mas não melhorei tudo o que podia, por exemplo não verifiquei se a alocação ou leitura no arquivo deu erro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>

typedef struct {
    char **matriz;
} Dado;

void ler_agumento (Dado *dado, int argc, char **argv) {
    dado->matriz = NULL;
    while (int opcao = getopt (argc,argv, "e::") != -1) if (opcao == 'e') dado->matriz = optarg;
}

void imprimir (FILE *file) {
    if (file == NULL) fprintf(stderr, "Erro ao abrir o arquivo.txt.");
    char *line = malloc(80);
    while(fgets(line, 80, file) != NULL) printf("%s", line);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Dado dado;
    dado.matriz = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) dado.matriz[i] = malloc(8);
    ler_argumento (&dado, argc, argv);
    FILE *file = fopen(dado.matriz,"r");
    imprimir(file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/FileBuffer.c).

Answer (score 0):

Gente, consegui resolver aqui. Agradeço a todos que me responderam.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>

typedef struct dado{
    // Deixei um asterisco apenas.
    char *matriz;

} Dado;

// Arrumei o parametro argv colocando colchetes.
void ler_agumento (Dado *dado, int argc, char *argv[]){

    int opcao;

   // Fiz alocao dinamica aqui.
   dado -> matriz = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)); 
   dado -> matriz = NULL;

    while (opcao = getopt (argc,argv, "e:") != -1){

        switch (opcao){

            case 'e':
                dado->matriz = optarg;
                break;
        }
    }
}

void imprimir (FILE *file){

    char *line = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));

    if(file == NULL) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Erro ao abrir o arquivo.txt.");
    }   

    while(fgets(line, 80, file) != NULL) {

        printf("%s", line);
    }     
}

int main(int argc, char **argv[]){

    Dado dado;

    ler_argumento (&dado, argc, argv);

    FILE *file = fopen(dado.matriz,"r");

    imprimir (file);

    fclose (file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mas você continua com o mesmo problema na assinatura da função `main`